# Handling file names with spaces in ogr2ogr?

Tags: shapefile, convert, ogr2ogr, batch

I'm trying to convert .shp files to .kml files. I used a batch file to find all .shp files in a directory and its sub-directories and convert them to .kml. Some converted and some gave me the error "Unable to open datasource with the following drivers". I worked out that it was not converting due to spaces existing in the file names. When I got rid of spaces in the file name, it converted.

With that said, I need the files to be the same name so that they can be referenced by other programs correctly. Is there a way either in ogr2ogr or in windows cmd line to accommodate for spaces in files names when being batch converted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two possibilities:

- Use wildcards to process all files in a directory:

`FOR %%F in (D:\Karten\shp\Gemeinden\*.shp) DO ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:31466 D:\Karten\shp\neu\%%~nxF %%F`

- Use quotation marks around path and filename:

`ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:31466 "D:\Karten\shp\Test 1.shp" "D:\Karten\shp\Test 2.shp"`

**EDIT**

This one works for me:

```
for /R %%F in (*.shp) do ogr2ogr -f "KML" "%%~dpnF.kml" "%%F"
```

Comment: Hi Andre, thanks for the help, but it still comes up with 'unable to open datasource' issue (for both cases), even for files without spaces. I re-tested with my old code (which I have delightfully stolen from another topic) and it still works for names without spaces.  the code is: for /R  %%f in (*.shp) do ogr2ogr -f "KML" %%~dpnf.kml %%f

Comment: Is there anything I can do to the code immediately above to accommodate fpor spaces in file names?

Comment: I tried, for /R  %f in ("*.shp") do ogr2ogr -f "KML" "%~dpnf.kml" %f , and I got the same error. Also tried 
for /R  %f in ("*.shp") do ogr2ogr -f "KML" %~"dpnf.kml" %f. Still same unfortunately.

Comment: Just one quotation still missing. See my extended answer.

Comment: Excellent!! Thank you very much for that! Now it does the conversion, but gave me a warning "Layer name ‘WP Waterbodies_WGS84’ adjusted to ‘WP_Waterbodies_WGS84’ for XML validity". Would I be correct in assuming that this is normal?

Comment: The kml specification does not seem to like blanks in layer names. But the kml driver solves the problem by inserting underlines, which should be ok.